# regex to negate from matched group

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to use regex to match anything but "id":digits part

I have come up with this "(\b(id":)(\d+)\b)" to find the id:byDigits pattern, but I need to negate that but haven't been able to get around it.

```
    [{"age":1,"id":123,"value":"14"},
     {"age":1,"id":4214,"value":"4324"},
    {"age":3,"id":4244,"value":"545"}]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option is to capture the rest of the string into groups and use it in the substituion as below

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/cRVA5C/2/

**Pattern:** `^([\s\S]*?)\s*"id":\d+,?\s*([\s\S]*?)$`

**Breakdown:**

- `([\s\S]*?)`: match any number of any characters before and after `"id":`. Capture it into groups `\1` and `\2`
- `\s*"id":\d+,?\s*`: match `"id"=\d+`, optionally preceded by *spaces* and optionally followed by *spaces* and `,`.
- In substituition, use `\1\2`, to get the desired output.

---

*Note:* Regex may not be the ideal tool for parsing JSON.